После загрузки видео через VK api оно находится в обработке
Загружаю видео используя api vk. Видео загружается, его можно смотреть в моих загрузках, но вот на личной странице или на стене сообщества видео обрабатывается. Думал, может с серверами что-то не так, но через сутки тоже самое.
        elif media_type == 'video':
            params.update({
                'video_id': uploaded_media['video_id'],
                'owner_id': uploaded_media['owner_id'],
                'title': 'Uploaded Video',
                'wall_post': 1,
                'is_private': 0,
                'privacy_view': 'all'
            })
            response = httpx.post('https://api.vk.com/method/video.save', params=params)


Затем отправляю wall.post в качестве attachments передаю видео
                    owner_id, media_id = VkMedia(vk_token).get_media(file_content, media_type)
                    attachments.append(f"{media_type}{owner_id}_{media_id}")
                if where_to_post == 1:
                    httpx.post(
                        f"https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=-{vk_id}&from_group=1&message={context[f'text_{group_id}']}&attachments={','.join(attachments)}&v=5.199",
                        headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {vk_token}"})
                elif where_to_post == 2:
                    httpx.post(
                        f"https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id={owner_id}&from_group=0&message={context[f'text_{group_id}']}&attachments={','.join(attachments)}&v=5.199",
                        headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {vk_token}"})


